# Как запретить проигрывать 2 видео ролика одновременно (не youtube)?

Tags: html5, видео

На одной странице есть несколько видео, которые добавлены через тег `video` HTML5. Как запретить их одновременное воспроизведение?

Правильнее, наверное, сделать так. Когда пользователь нажимает на воспроизведение другого ролика, первый останавливается.

Comment: спасибо! решил применить ваш способ к html5 аудио, заменил термины video на audio, но ничего не получилось :( а хотел, чтобы после окончания проигрывания в одном плеере начинал звучать следующий

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, это больше относится к javascript, чем к html.

```js
const videos = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('video'));
let playing = true;

videos.forEach(video => {
  video.addEventListener('play', function() {
    if (playing) {
      videos.forEach(el => {
        el.pause();
      });
    }
    if (this.paused) {
      playing = false;
      this.play();
    } else {
      playing = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<video controls poster="http://www.jplayer.org/video/poster/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270.png">
  <source src='http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270_h264aac.m4v' type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
  <source src='http://www.jplayer.org/video/ogv/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270.ogv' type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />Your browser does not support the HTML5 Video spec.
</video>

<video controls poster="http://www.jplayer.org/video/poster/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270.png">
  <source src='http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270_h264aac.m4v' type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
  <source src='http://www.jplayer.org/video/ogv/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270.ogv' type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />Your browser does not support the HTML5 Video spec.
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arVideos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
for (var i = arVideos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var elmVideo = arVideos[i];
    elmVideo.autoplay = false;
}
```